# converting oracle's listagg to postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, syntax-error, string-aggregation

I am trying to convert some Oracle queries to Postgres and came across `listagg`.

*Oracle code*

```
select max(eta) eta, mso_id, listagg(carrier_name, ',') 
within group (order by eta) as carrier 
from tb_flight_schedule group by mso_id;
```

I found out that Postgres's equivalent of `listagg` is `string_agg` and proceeded to swap the `listagg` with `string_agg`. However, I am encountering error (**ERROR:  function string_agg(character varying, unknown, date) does not exist**). Am I missing something in the query? Postgres query is below:

```
select max(eta) eta, mso_id, string_agg(carrier_name, ',') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY eta) as carrier 
from tb_flight_schedule group by mso_id;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Postgres, the `within group` clause is only used for orderd-set aggregate functions - i.e., functions that **require** an `order by` clause (e.g., the percentile functions). An optional `order by` clause, such as `string_agg`'s, goes inside the function's arguments:

```
SELECT   MAX(eta) eta, mso_id, STRING_AGG(carrier_name, ',' ORDER BY eta) AS carrier 
FROM     tb_flight_schedule
GROUP BY mso_id;
```

Comment: oh I see. Thank you very much! :)